# Visual C# BackgroundWorker Object is currently in use elsewhere

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

Hello and thanks for reading my thread! I would like to seek advice for my code because after a lot of searching I couldn't find anything to solve this particular problem. I've googled and searched on stackoverflow and all the solutions somehow didn't work (or I didn't know how to implement them). Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using System.Threading ;

    namespace Motion_Detection
    {
         public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            private FilterInfoCollection VideoCaptureDevices;
            private VideoCaptureDevice FinalVideo;

        private void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Bitmap video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            pictureBox1.Image = video;
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            VideoCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            foreach (FilterInfo VideoCaptureDevice in VideoCaptureDevices)
            {
                devicesList.Items.Add(VideoCaptureDevice.Name);
                devicesList.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FinalVideo = new VideoCaptureDevice(VideoCaptureDevices[devicesList.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
            FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);

            FinalVideo.Start();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = null;
            FinalVideo.Stop();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            worker.CancelAsync();
        }

        private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (!worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                Bitmap map = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image); // this line throws the error

                for (int x = 0; x < pictureBox1.Width; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < pictureBox1.Height; y++)
                    {
                        Color pixel = map.GetPixel(x, y);

                        if (pixel.R == 255 && pixel.G == 0 && pixel.B == 0)
                        {
                            // detected red pixel
                        }
                    }
                }

                Thread.Sleep(100); // check every 100ms or any other given interval
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm using the Aforge video dlls to access my web camera. This part works, I can access and read the stream from it, when I dump it into picturebox1 it shows up perfectly, without any lag whatsoever.

Now I'm toying a bit around with motion detection and for the first, I wanted to see if I can detect a pixel of a certain color appearing in front of the camera. Because I need to loop through every pixel, I had to put this on a different thread else it kept freezing my GUI and the display started to lag.

The issue is because I did this, I don't know how to properly access the picturebox.image content from the background worker without triggering the error from the title. Some people on the internet suggested using lock() but I never did this nor I know what I should lock() here. I never worked with multithreading before just because in the end I could never handle the access violations..

To fix this problem I tried things like try finally block although even within the try block, I've gotten the same exception. I assume that there is a cleaner way to do what I've mentioned but I can't really get my head around which one that might be.

I hope that my first post here on the forums was clear and understandable as possible.

Thanks in Regards
~ Ilhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant/shouldn't access pictureBox1 unless on the UI thread.

I think you need to do something like this:

```
private void GetImage(out Bitmap img)
{
    img = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
}

void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap img = null;
    Invoke(new Action(() => GetImage(out img)));
    // Do what you want with the bitmap
}
```

Accessing a control on a winform will throw an exception if its not on the UI thread.
You can find out if you are on the correct thread with pictureBox1.InvokeRequired.
Calling Invoke will send a message to the UI thread to do the passed delegate and then it will wait for the passed delegate to complete. Calling BeginInvoke will send the message but not wait.

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked! That invoke thing looks .. hmm strange I never needed to invoke anything yet could you perhaps (for my own good) explain in a few words what exactly was the solution?

Comment: I'll give a shot, anyone please correct me if I am wrong or misunderstanding as I am interested too.  What he did is call a background worker(thread) to do the long running task off the UI thread so your UI could continue on as it needed without hanging.  Invoke allows you to get a bitmap from the picturebox, which can only be accessed from the UI thread, by calling the method on the main thread.  The worker thread then waits for that method running on the main thread to return the bitmap. When it returns, it goes to your worker thread to be processed off of the main thread again.